# WCF ado.net Insert record (at end)

Tags: c#, database, insert, windows-phone-8, odata

Stackers,

I have been troubled with this problem for so long, that i finally decided to post my question here.

This is whats bothering me. I am writing an app for windowsphone 8. This app revolves around a local and a remote database. The local database part was the easy part. But now, i want to use my WCF service to insert records into my remote db (using ADO.NET with the service at serverside). I have succesfully  inserted records in the remote database but there's a catch (atleast for what im aiming at).

My database table (in which im inserting) has a primary key and i don't want to tell/insert this primary key when I insert data into the database. I just want to insert my new record after the last record. Is there any way to do this?

This is what i have so far:

```
private MeasurementEntities Context;
Context = new MeasurementEntities(new Uri("http://192.168.11.240:85/NFCDataService.svc/"));

public void SaveAnwsersToDbLocal(bool ans1, bool ans2, bool ans3)
        {
            Measurement temp = new Measurement();

            temp.Anwser1 = ans1;
            temp.Anwser2 = ans2;
            temp.Anwser3 = ans3;
            temp.MeasurementId = 1; // this is the primary key, and want to get rid of this.
            // i want to insert at end of database. but how?

            // add to local collection.
            _MeasurementCollection.Add(temp);

            Context.AddToMeasurements(temp);

            Context.BeginSaveChanges(SaveChangesCallback, temp);

            //if wifi is on:
            UploadMeasurements();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this was really stupid. In my mssql table, i had not enabled the feature to add rows with auto increment. Atleast, i had it enabled but the increment was set to 0. So it would point to the same record.